# Do I need a breaker box in my shed?

Tags: wiring, receptacle, circuit-breaker

I just finished building a new house and I want to run a 10-2 UF-B 120’ to my shed from my main panel on the outside of the house that has a sub panel for the well and a generator.

I plan on installing a 30 amp breaker and running the 10-2 to the shed. Can I run the wire directly to the outlets or do I need to install a breaker box in the shed also. I’m running the 10-2 to 6 20 amp outlets. Is it ok to use #12 for my pigtails?

[image: meter main, presumably on the main house]

Comment: What are you expecting to power with the generator?

Comment: UF-B is rated for direct burial with a minimum of 24" of cover (assuming you're not driving over it). However, should you _ever_ need to upgrade the circuit or find that the cable has been damaged, you'll have to dig the whole thing up and replace it. Instead, I'd _strong_ recommend burying conduit (requiring as little as 6" of cover, depending on conduit type) and pulling individual THHN wires through it. The wire itself will be much cheaper, offsetting the cost of the conduit, the digging will be much easier, and you can pull additional/replacement wire with ease in the future.

Comment: Where is your generator inlet? (Is it one of those conduits going down?)

Answer (score 1):

You will need a sub as the max amps is 20 for the lights and receptacles.  A small sub will require 4 wire or 10-3 with ground and since it is a seperate building additional grounding rods.

If you don’t want to put that much in you could run a multi wire branch circuit with a 20 amp feeder breaker but remember all receptacles in a out building require GFCI protection and they don’t play well on multiwire branch circuits but it can be done.

Comment: Doesn't an outbuilding also need a shutoff switch at the building as well?

Comment: And let's not neglect **Price that #10/3 UF copper and then price #2-2-2-4 4-wire aluminum mobile home feeder...**

Comment: Yeah, I was just thinking this job is better done with TWO 6-6-6-6 aluminum feeders, won't cost much more than a single 10/2 and will allow safe/legal generator hookup.  Also 50A on both feeds, so you're set for any future need.

Comment: @manassehkatz with a mwbc on a 20 amp feeder a double pole switch can be located inside 225.32. I agree up sizing and using aluminum is the way to go but some want copper and the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

You can feed 120v using 10/2 with a 20 amp breaker and all you will need is a disconnect switch. You could run 10/3 for 240v, but it is not necessary if you don't need 240v capability. The switch will need to be located outside or inside the shed where the feeder enters the building. The switch can be a simple 20A rated light switch, you need a double pole switch if you upgrade to 10/3.

If you feed the 10/2 from a 30 amp breaker then at very least you will need to install a fused disconnect or small circuit breaker enclosure to limit current to 20A for receptacles. Once you pass through that protection the whole circuit can be wired with #12, not just the pigtails.

If you install a small electrical panel with a (minimum) 30A main breaker, with separate 20 amp breakers (or 15A breakers if you use #14 wire) for lights and receptacles then you will need to add ground rods at the shed. I think at that distance even with a single circuit a ground rod is a good idea, but there is a special exception for a single circuit (or single multiwire branch circuit) that allows omitting the ground rods.

Using larger aluminum feeders may prove to be a lower cost than 10/2 copper UF, but 10/2 UF may still be a good choice if you feed with a 20 amp breaker because #8 or larger wire will not easily terminate in a simple light switch.